# How to get same font in matplotlib plot as latex?

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I want the font in my python plot to be consistent with the latex. I found another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687213/how-to-obtain-the-same-font-style-size-etc-in-matplotlib-output-as-in-latex). But it doesn't work on my computer and the error is

```
KeyError: 'text.latex.unicode is not a valid rc parameter (see rcParams.keys() for a list of valid parameters)'
```

Can anyone provide me a method that can be used for current version of python?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib 

font = {'family' : 'serif',
         'size'   : 12,
         'serif':  'cmr10'
         }

matplotlib.rc('font', **font)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. But I encountered some user warnings as follows:

UserWarning: cmr10 font should ideally be used with mathtext, set axes.formatter.use_mathtext to True
UserWarning: Glyph 8722 (\N{MINUS SIGN}) missing from current font.
UserWarning: Glyph 8722 (\N{MINUS SIGN}) missing from current font.
  fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)

And the negative sign in the ticks was missing.

Comment: Does the rest show up fine with the correct font? If yes, add this line as well: `matplotlib.rc('axes', unicode_minus=False)`